# Why I get a success message saying `2 rows inserted` after executing the query more than once?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables with one-to-one relationship:

```
               post_views table
    ___________________________________
   |        |             |           |
   |   id   |   post_id   |   views   |
   |________|_____________|___________|




                   posts table
    __________________________________________
   |        |           |          |         |
   |   id   |   title   |   text   |    ..   |
   |________|___________|__________|_________|
```

`post_id` from `post_views` table is joined with `id` from `posts` table.

The `id` in both tables is primary and auto incremented, And the `post_id` is unique.

Here is a screenshot of the indexes for `post_views`:
https://prnt.sc/k6no10

Each post should has only one row in `post_views` table.

I run this query to insert a new row or increase the views, If that `post_id` exists:

```
INSERT INTO post_views (`post_id`, `views`) VALUES (1, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `views` = `views`+1
```

It's executed successfully and a new row is inserted:

```
 ____________________________________
|          |             |           |
|    id    |   post_id   |   views   |
|__________|_____________|___________|
|          |             |           |
|    1     |     1       |    1      |
|          |             |           |
|__________|_____________|___________|
```

Then when I run the same query again to increase the views, I get a success message saying that `2 rows inserted` and the row is now:

```
____________________________________
|          |             |           |
|    id    |   post_id   |   views   |
|__________|_____________|___________|
|          |             |           |
|    1     |     1       |    2      |
|          |             |           |
|__________|_____________|___________|
```

And that's what I want, but if I run the query with a new `post_id`:

```
INSERT INTO post_views (`post_id`, `views`) VALUES (2, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `views` = `views`+1
```

I get that:

```
____________________________________
|          |             |           |
|    id    |   post_id   |   views   |
|__________|_____________|___________|
|          |             |           |
|    1     |     1       |    2      |
|__________|_____________|___________|  
|          |             |           |
|    3     |     2       |    1      |    
|__________|_____________|___________|
```

The `id` is 3 instead of 2, So each time I run the query with the same `post_id` is like I'm inserting a new row with an id.

So if I run the query with `post_id = 3` three times, The news id will be 7.

Is that's normal?

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-issue.  The `id`s in a table are not intended to be sequential with no gaps.  Ensuring such logic is *very* expensive.  It requires locking the whole table for the inserts.  Database engines wisely do not do this.

In a single threaded environment -- no concurrent transactions -- you can get around this by doing separate `update` and `insert` commands:

```
update post_views
    set views = views + 1
    where post_id = 1;

insert into post_views (post_id, views)
    select post_id, 1
    from (select 1 as post_id) x
    where not exists (select 1 from post_views pv where pv.post_id = x.post_id);
```

The `where` prevents the `insert` from even attempting an update, so no new id is generated.  However, **I strongly advise you not to take this approach.**  It is not thread-safe.  In a concurrent processing world, it will not guarantee what you want.

Your case is even stranger.  You have no need for the `id` column in `post_views`.  The `post_id` can be both a primary key and a foreign key:

```
create table post_views (
    post_id int primary key,
    views int default 0,
    constraint fk_post_views_post_id foreign key (post_id) references posts(id)
);
```

If you set the data up this way, you won't have the id, and you won't have the problem at all.  Or, you could just add `views` into the `posts` table and deal with one table.

Comment: What is better for performance and speed? to separate the two tables or to combine them? I mean if the posts table contains thousands of posts, To find the id of the post, And then to display the post viewed posts ordered by views.
what is better?

Comment: @Dan . . . There are circumstances where having them in separate tables would help performance.  This would be true if the `posts` table is being commonly used and you don't want to deal with update locks.  However, if you are not expecting dozens or more transactions per second, you might start off with a single table and address performance when it becomes an issue.